# Configuration issue with SpringBoot JDBC derby inmemory

Tags: spring-boot, memory, jdbc, derby, hikaricp

Trying to set up a Derby in-memory database with SpringBoot, but I get an error.

**Gradle dependencies:**

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.apache.derby:derbyshared:10.15.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.derby:derbytools:10.15.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.derby:derbyclient:10.15.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:memory:;create=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

**Description:**

Failed to bind properties under '' to `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`:

```
Property: driver-class-name
Value: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
Reason: org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot
```

*Help is much appreciated.*

Answer (score 1):

Remove [driver-class-name](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) row

> **driverClassName**
> HikariCP will attempt to resolve a driver through the DriverManager based solely on the jdbcUrl, but for some older drivers the driverClassName must also be specified. **Omit this property** unless you get an obvious error message indicating that the driver was not found. Default: none

and add `dataSourceClassName` ( or `data-source-class-name`):

```
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource
```

> We recommended using dataSourceClassName instead of jdbcUrl

Answer (score 1):

I needed to replace derbyclient.jar with derby.jar for working locally in memory:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.apache.derby:derby:10.15.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.derby:derbyshared:10.15.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.derby:derbytools:10.15.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

Thanks for the help!